# In my Julia 1.0.0 REPL, LOAD_PATH returns unexpected results

Tags: julia

My Julia REPL Help provides the following for LOAD_PATH:

```
help?> LOAD_PATH
search: LOAD_PATH

  LOAD_PATH

  An array of paths for using and import statements to consdier as project environments or package directories when
  loading code. See Code Loading.
```

Here is my output for LOAD_PATH at the prompt:

```
julia> LOAD_PATH  # What is the output below?
3-element Array{String,1}:
 "@"
 "@v#.#"
 "@stdlib"
```

The output shown above for LOAD_PATH seems strange.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [Seeking opinion] hey mate, how's your general Julia programming experience?  Do you find any major drawback?  As I'm thinking to start learning it

Comment: I am very, very happy with my general Julia programming experience.   In my opinion, the language still needs a faster and more accurate on-line documentation search engine, but that should come with time.  I also wish the built-in print/println function or the standard library macro @printf had a flag for adding commas to numbers, but I did provide a workaround in one of my stackoverflow answers.  Julia's ability to infer types and produce custom machine code for a function depending on that type inference is for me a game changer.  I am happy to answer other questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you see there is the [`DEFAULT_LOAD_PATH`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/70c7298110318cc984c230b7ce61bed7821a57bb/base/initdefs.jl#L73).

Let me cite comments from the [relevant section of the source code](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/70c7298110318cc984c230b7ce61bed7821a57bb/base/initdefs.jl#L57):

```
## LOAD_PATH, HOME_PROJECT & ACTIVE_PROJECT ##

# JULIA_LOAD_PATH: split on `:` (or `;` on Windows)
# first empty entry is replaced with DEFAULT_LOAD_PATH, the rest are skipped
# entries starting with `@` are named environments:
#  - the first three `#`s in a named environment are replaced with version numbers
#  - `@stdlib` is a special name for the standard library and expands to its path
```

In other words,

- `"@"`: is for loading things relative to the current path (not completely sure here, see update below)
- `"@v#.#"`: will become the path to the `v1.0` environment (assuming you are on 1.0).
- `"@stdlib"`: will become the path to the stdlibs

This should probably be explained more precisely in the Pkg docs somewhere. Mind [filing an issue over there](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Pkg.jl/issues/new)? (UPDATE: See https://github.com/JuliaLang/Pkg.jl/issues/757)

**UPDATE:**

One can play around with the method `Base.load_path_expand(a::AbstractString)` to see what things become eventually:

```
julia> Base.load_path_expand.(LOAD_PATH.*"/test")
3-element Array{String,1}:
 "\\test\\Project.toml"
 "C:\\Users\\carsten\\.julia\\environments\\v1.0\\test\\Project.toml"
 "C:\\Users\\carsten\\.julia\\environments\\stdlib\\test\\Project.toml"
```

Comment: Great answer!  Thanks.

Comment: @cristnbr sadly, `LOAD_PATH` is yet another example of how dire the julia in-REPL documentation is. The devs should invest some time to read [the latest winner of the Ig-Nobel prizes](https://idle.slashdot.org/story/18/09/16/0431250/research-proving-people-dont-rtfm-resent-over-featured-products-wins-ig-nobel-prize)

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou although I do not disagree, modifying `LOAD_PATH` is probably irrelevant for most people. There are way more important things to add to the documentation.

Comment: `LOAD_PATH` is just the current example. The discrepancy between in-REPL and "manual" quality is extremely striking in about 95% of julia functionality. Compare in-REPL documentation with something like R, octave, matlab, or python. No comparison. Half the functions, including important ones, are undocumented. It's unacceptable.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou As a newcomer to Julia, Sept. 4, 2018 first code, version 1.0.0 is my first version, I definitely concur with what you are saying.  I am moving to Julia from Python and I do see a different level in the quality of documentation, as you state.  However, I like Julia so much I am overlooking the documentation problem and hoping the docs mature with the language.  As a newcomer it helps to know that my discomfort with various aspects of the Julia documentation is not just me.

Comment: @crstnbr Thanks for pointing out the `Base.load_path_expand.(LOAD_PATH.*"/test")` example!

Comment: @Julia Learner: I also find Julia documentation more of a barrier, than enabler. I think parts of documentation just need to scrapped and shortened (eg Pkg docs), and it is a hard thing to do, trimming the text. Also the introduction to a new adopter could have benefited from descibing the mind model (eg `environment=set on installed packages=Project.toml+Manifest.toml`, `ABC/src/ABC.jl` folder template, the latter is just assumed and buried in docs, should be a top thing to tell). Still like Julia nonetheless the docs.