# what is `@.` in Julia `--project` command line option?

Tags: command-line-interface, julia

When starting Julia in the command line one can specify project directory. One of the options is `@.`, resumably the current directory. What is `@.` in this context?

```
# from `julia --help`
--project[={<dir>|@.}]    Set <dir> as the home project/environment
```

From the [docs](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/604046c1e1063d393261c07fc66a4f825b244697/doc/src/manual/environment-variables.md#julia_project):

> If the variable is set to @., Julia tries to find a project directory that contains Project.toml or JuliaProject.toml file from the current directory and its parents.

I realise the cli `--project` argument parsing occurs in this [C code](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/44dd917cbaf5b0a13f146e83a292a5f4412679ac/src/jloptions.c#L397-L399), and apparently used by this [init code](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/7920a2a1fbef934a08b61b4bb26c3147f0bf9e41/base/initdefs.jl#L128-L145), although I'm not sure of the sequence of events in between.

Specifically in [initdefs.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/7920a2a1fbef934a08b61b4bb26c3147f0bf9e41/base/initdefs.jl#L128-L145) we have:

```
project = (JLOptions().project != C_NULL ?
    unsafe_string(Base.JLOptions().project) :
    get(ENV, "JULIA_PROJECT", nothing))
HOME_PROJECT[] =
    project == nothing ? nothing :
    project == "" ? nothing :
    project == "@." ? current_project() : abspath(project)
```

My reading of this code is that `@.` is just an arbitrary token, could it have been a simple `.` for cli? How does Julia search *"the current directory and its parents.*"

There is similar notation used in `LOAD_PATH`(`["@", "@v#.#", "@stdlib"]`), 
as discussed [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/what-are-the-symbols-in-load-path/15420/2) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52378974/in-my-julia-1-0-0-repl-load-path-returns-unexpected-results). Does `@.` belong to the same family of expansion as `LOAD_PATH` symbols?

Comment: See related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52378974/in-my-julia-1-0-0-repl-load-path-returns-unexpected-results and https://github.com/JuliaLang/Pkg.jl/issues/757

Comment: @crstnbr: the first link is actually cited in question, the issue about docs for named enviroments `"@.", "@", "@v#.#", "@stdlib"` I fully support, but maybe just an extended docstring for [Base.load_path_expand](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/7920a2a1fbef934a08b61b4bb26c3147f0bf9e41/base/initdefs.jl#L149-L185) is needed, as Pkg.jl is just a user of that funcitonality.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Home project and `--project`

The `--project` flag defines the "home project" or "home environment". An environment is defined by a `Project.toml`/`Manifest.toml` and defines which package are available for `using`/`import`.

You can set `--project` to (i) a directory (with or without a `Project.toml`) (ii) a path to a `Project.toml` or (iii) to `@.`. (i) and (ii) are pretty self-explanatory -- Julia will consider the project located at the path to be the home project. Now for (iii), if you set `--project=@.` Julia will try to find an *existing* `Project.toml` file and use that as the home project. Consider the following example:

```
~$ tree .
.
├── A
└── Project.toml

1 directory, 1 file
```

where `A` is an empty directory. We can try (i) and (ii) easily:

```
# existing file
[~]$ julia --project=Project.toml -E 'Base.active_project()'
"~/Project.toml"

# existing directory
[~]$ julia --project=A -E 'Base.active_project()'
"~/A/Project.toml"

# non-existing directory
[~]$ julia --project=B -E 'Base.active_project()'
"~/B/Project.toml"

# non-existing file
[~]$ julia --project=B/Project.toml -E 'Base.active_project()'
"~/B/Project.toml"
```

Note that in the three last examples above the `Project.toml` file *do not exist*, but it will be created if needed (e.g. when using [`Pkg`](https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1/) to manipulate packages).

Now, compare this with the behaviour of `@.`, which will look for an *existing* project file:

```
# from our root directory
[~]$ julia --project=@. -E 'Base.active_project()'
"~/Project.toml"

# from inside the A directory
[~/A]$ julia --project=@. -E 'Base.active_project()'
"~/Project.toml"
```

where in both cases we found the same `Project.toml` file. With the `@.` option Julia first look in the current directory for a `Project.toml` file, and if not found, steps up one level to the parent folder and looks there, and so on. This is what happened in the second example; Julia did not find a `Project.toml` file in the empty `A` directory, so we moved up to the parent directory, and found the `Project.toml` we have there.

And yes, we could have choosen some other token for this, but not `.` since that already has a meaning; it is the path to the current directory, and a perfectly valid path to use with `--project`.

### The load path and `"@"`

To load a package `Example` it is not enough that we define a home project with `Example` in its `[deps]` section; the home project also needs to show up in Julias load path (`Base.load_path()`). By default the load path is expanded from `["@", "@v#.#", "@stdlib"]` where `"@v#.#"` expands to `~/.julia/environments/v#.#` with `#` replaced with Julias major and minor version number, and `"@stdlib"` expands to the directory with Julias standard library. `"@"` expands to 1. an active project (activated with `Pkg.activate`/`pkg> activate`) or 2. the home project. We can check the expanded load path with `Base.load_path()`:

```
# without home project; @ expands to nothing
[~]$ julia -E 'Base.load_path()'
["~/.julia/environments/v1.0/Project.toml", "~/julia10/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0"]

# with home project; @ expands to our specified home project
[~]$ julia --project=@. -E 'Base.load_path()'
["~/Project.toml", "~/.julia/environments/v1.0/Project.toml", "~/julia10/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0"]
```

And finally, if we remove `"@"` from the load path it does not matter that we have defined a home project:

```
[~]$ export JULIA_LOAD_PATH="" && julia --project=@. -E 'Base.load_path()'
String[]
```

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer. It was not immidiately clear that `--project` accepts non-existing paths. Also playing with `Base.load_path_expand("@")` on a case you mention (berfore and after `activate`) is quite enlighting. I think a proper docstring (maybe based on this answer) for `Base.load_path_expand()`, where named environment resolution takes place, also could have helped: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/7920a2a1fbef934a08b61b4bb26c3147f0bf9e41/base/initdefs.jl#L149-L185

Answer (score 4):

Based on @fredrikekre answer, wrote a script to explore behaviour of `Base.load_path()`, `Base.active_project()`, `Base.current_project()`.

init_me.jl:

```
"""
Explore Base.load_path() behaviour in diffferent situations.

Run this file as:

    julia init_me.jl
    julia --project=@. init_me.jl
    julia --project=. init_me.jl

Try running in a folder that has or does not have Project.toml file.    
"""    

MESSAGE = Dict(true => " (exists)", false => " (does not exist)")
exist(path)::Bool = isfile(path) || isdir(path)
printexist(path::String) = println("  ", path, MESSAGE[exist(path)])
printexist(nothing) = println("nothing")
printf2(s,n=8) = print("  " * s * ' '^(n-length(s)))

p_ = Base.JLOptions().project
project_option = (p_ != C_NULL) ? unsafe_string(p_) : "option not provided"
println("--project:\n  ", project_option)

println("load_path():")
for path in Base.load_path()
    printexist(path)
end

println("Base.active_project():")
printexist(Base.active_project())
println("Base.current_project():")
printexist(Base.current_project())

println("alias expansion with Base.load_path_expand():")
for alias in ["@.", "@", "@stdlib", "@v1.0"] 
    printf2(alias)
    printexist(Base.load_path_expand(alias))
end
```

The results are as following:

- basecase: `julia --project=@. init_me.jl` in folder with Project.toml file produces most expected result
- `julia --project=. init_me.jl` fails on folders where path has non-ASCII characters
- a folder without `Project.toml` can become an active project upon `--project=<some dir without Project.toml>`
- sometimes `Base.active_project()` is not `Base.current_project()`